# Transferring players items (steam)

Tags: api, steam

Can I transfer item from one player inventory to other player through steam API?
in the official documentation, I found no mention of the possibility of such operations

Comment: https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot

Answer (score 0):

You can do a trade with that player if they are in your friend list.